# Why underscorejs use blocking style without callback?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Unlike nodejs non-blocking callback styles, all underscorejs are using sync style. For some heavy functions like _.template, I do think it will block.

I don't know why underscorejs doesn't use callbacks, or it doesn't matter because they are all in-memory calculation?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Because it doesn't have any asynchronous work to do?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because asynchronous design is not at the core of underscore like it is with node.js. Underscore favors simplicity and a familiarity to developers who already know jQuery.